# ¿Cómo puedo comparar un elemento de la lista con todos los de otra lista hasta que se encuentre uno igual?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, comparaciones

Quiero comparar los primeros cinco elementos de una lista con los elementos de la otra, si encuentra el elemento mas pequeño de la lista que coincidan entre los dos imprimirlo

```
zonaA=[]
un=["A12"," A7"]
zona=["chedraui"]
a="chedraui"
for g in range (20):
    zonaA.append("A{}".format(g+1))
if a=="chedraui":
    b=set(zonaA[:5])&set(un)
    if b:
        print(b)
    if not b:
        print("NO")
```

En este caso serian los primeros 5 elementos de `zonaA` compararlos con `un`, si lo encuentran lo guarda y si no debería seguir con los otros 5 dígitos de `zonaA` hasta encontrar el elemento parecido, dando prioridad al menor numero de la lista `un` en este caso seria darle prioridad al "A7", aun no encuentro como implementar el ciclo y que el `set` tambien busque con el elemento `[1]` de `un`.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí hay un ejemplo de como comparar 2 listas y guardar el valor que coincide en una tercera, para ordenar los elementos de una lista de menor a mayor puedes usar la función sort() pero solo sirve para elementos numéricos.

```
listA[]
listB[]
save_list = []

for elementA in listA:
for elementB in  listB:
    if elementA == elementB:
        print(f"{elementA}")
        save_list.append(elementA)
```